# Can I use the Same WordPress plugin used twice or more?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I wanna know if is it possible to use the same plugin for 2 different websites?

For example, I'm buying a plugin from envanto market and I will install that to my current website. However, I'm worried that my website will be infected by malware later on (my websites under siteground are always being infected with no apparent reason so I'm quite worried)

If ever that happens, I'm just gonna create a new website (to avoid costly malware removal) and possibly install the same plugin I purchased from envanto.

Please help.

Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the same plugin but on other website / domain. You have to just enter purchase code each time when you install plugin.
Before doing that please confirm with plugin author team if they have restricted the use / installation of plugin.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can ofcourse use any plugin on any number of websites.

But, since you have purchased that plugin you will have to consider the license information. If you have purchased the plugin for only one website, then before using it on any other website you will have to disable and delete that plugin from previous website.

Developer of the plugin that you have purchased will be able to help you better in this case.